# Android aviary converting to fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, onresume, aviary

How Can I convert the code below so it can work in Fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onResume" );
    super.onResume();

    if ( getIntent() != null ) {
        handleIntent( getIntent() );
        setIntent( new Intent() );
    }
}
```

I have tried this. but It doesn't worked.

```
public void onResume() {
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "onResume" );
    super.onResume();

    if ( getActivity().getIntent() != null ) {
        handleIntent( getActivity().getIntent() );
        getActivity().setIntent( new Intent() );
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly does not work?

Comment: FWIW, that seems like a bad design to be altering the activity's intent in a fragment.  Activities use fragments, but fragments should not use activities.  Thus I would suggest keeping that code in the activity itself.